# Adding a big data table from MS word to an array?

Tags: c, arrays

I am working on a database project, where I want to create an array as follows:

```
unsigned char* drillSize[][10] = { 
{"0.3678",  "23.222",  "MN", "89000", ".000236", "678", "ZX", "8563", "LX", "0.678"},

{"0.3678",  "23.222",  "MN", "89000", ".000236", "678", "ZX", "8563", "LX", "0.678"},
.
.
.
 //around 6000 rows                              }
```

I have been provided with this data in an Microsoft Word file. If I were to key in the data manually it might take weeks; is there a way to insert commas and inverted commas for each element by some means?

Comment: Are you using C++? If so, tag it as such.

Comment: This is in C. Sorry Jonathon being a new member i am not allowed to modify tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with regular expressions.

If your data is structured in any way like a csv file you can just import it into your program in some way and then slice it up with basic string functions.

In php I'd

```
$input = file_get_contents($myfile) //lets say this contains a text: 1,2,3,4,5
$sliced = explode(",",$input);
$myarray = null; //our variable
$output = "\$myarray = new array("; //creating a template for an array as a String
//some logic with the $sliced array if you need
...
$output .= implode(",",$sliced); //we put it back as string
$output .= ");"; //close the array
eval($output); //after this its in php's scope
print_r($myarray);
```

Basically that's what you need in a more complex form. If the text is not that structured you might need some regular expression library for C, but I'd recommend creating a text in Python, Perl or something which has more support and more flexible then copy the code manually back to C.